I am trying to connect the SalesforceSObjectSinkConnector in my local machine
This is the error I am facing while configuring the connector:
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value [] for configuration bootstrap.servers: Empty list
    at io.confluent.connect.utils.validators.NonEmptyListValidator.ensureValid(NonEmptyListValidator.java:21)

But I mentioned the bootstrap server mentioned in the confluent documentation.
I tried to provide them in the array also but it was not accepting the array value in bootstrap properties.

Please clarify what command you're running and what property files you're using
